# PHP read remote file through FTP connection

Tags: php, ftp

I have simple code to load data from txt file to mysql, it works perfect but my last one problem is that my file is on ftp server not in local folder. 
Below is my code how rewrite this line to connect with my file on ftp (test.txt) with using credentials?

```
$open=fopen('test.txt','r');

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','db_name');

if(!$conn)
{
    die(mysqli_error());
}

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM test");

$open = fopen('test.txt','r');

fgets($open);
fgets($open);
while (!feof($open)) 
{
  $getTextLine = fgets($open);
  $explodeLine = explode("|",$getTextLine);

  list($Login,$Inday,$Start_przerwy,$Koniec_przerwy,$Czas_przerwy,$Odcinek) = $explodeLine;

  $qry = "insert into test (Login,Inday,Start_przerwy,Koniec_przerwy,Czas_przerwy,Odcinek) values('".$Login."','".$Inday."','".$Start_przerwy."','".$Koniec_przerwy."','".$Czas_przerwy."','".$Odcinek."')";
  mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
}
fclose($open);
echo "done";
```

Comment: You might want to consider writing a shell script and then having PHP execute the shell script. You could even pass variables to it.

Comment: This is open to (sql) injection; use a prepared statement if you don't want your database to suddenly disappear one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply the same but define protocol `ftp://` and `username`, `password`

```
$file = "ftp://username:pa‌​ssword@hostname/path/to/test.txt";
$open = fopen($file, "r");
```

or:

```
$file = "ftp://username:pa‌​ssword@hostname/path/to/test.txt";
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents($file));

foreach($lines AS $line) {
  $line = trim($line);
  // body of while
}
```

no need for `ftp_*` [methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php), keep it simple (: